# I give you life or I'll protect you

Tags: riddle

> When I am with same thing as myself, I give you life.
>
> But when I am with two others same as myself, I will protect you.

Who am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it

> O

When I am with same thing as myself, I give you life.

> O2 is oxigen, which you need to breath and thus live.

But when I am with two others same as myself, I will protect you.

> O3 is ozone, which protects against the deadly rays of the sun.